# execute a smart contract function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum

Is there something wrong with my command?

```
contract.methods.thu().send(
   { from: senderAddress, 
     gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(GAS_PRICE), 
     gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(GAS_LIMIT)
   }
);
```

When I execute it, I get this error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

I'm pretty sure that I did execute the similar command successfully but now I don't know why I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

`gasLimit` is actually represented by `gas` as the gas limiter according to the docs: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

```
contract.methods.thu().send(
   { from: senderAddress, 
     gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(GAS_PRICE), 
     gas: web3.utils.toHex(GAS_LIMIT)
   }
)
```

Also, it's probably best to use the parameter types of `gasPrice` `(String)` and `gas` `(Number)` from the docs.